# How do I fetch a json response from ionic-native HTTP get method?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm studying Ionic and I've started working with some APIs and now I'm having some trouble using the CountryAPI (https://fabian7593.github.io/CountryAPI/). I'm using the GET method to receive a json with informations of all the countries that have "united" in their names. Here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import firebase from 'firebase'
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http'    

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  public resultados: any

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HTTP) {
    this.mget()
  }

  sair(){
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot('login'))
  }


  mget(){

    let url = 'http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=united'

    this.http.get(url, {}, {}).then( data => {

      console.log(data.data); // data received by server

      let results = JSON.parse(data['_body']).results

    })
  }

}
```

when I console.log the data received it's all ok and beautiful in a json format, but it's not possible to subscribe for the ionic-native http.get method and if I try something like

```
for(let i = 0; i < news.length(); i ++){
      console.log(news[i])
      this.noticias.push({
        name: news[i].name,
        nativeName: news[i].nativeName
      })
    }
```

is no good, it accuses that news.length() is not a function.

I need to fetch all the data in a vector so I can display it in a list with ion-list in my app.

Comment: you just need to do news.length not require the parenthesis..

Comment: [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?v=example) is a property not a function

Answer (score -1):

To Fetch the JSON data from country API you should add the provider like this:

```
ionic g provider countryService
```

and then hit the API like the below code in countryService.ts

```
  // ******************************** listing API ***********************************
  load() {

    console.log(' RestServiceProvider Load Method fro listing');
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get("http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=united")
        .map(res => res.json().response)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
```

For getting the name of the country you should call this method in your **HomePage**  like this:

```
  this.countryService.load().then(data => {
        this.country= data;
      });
```

show name in UI by using **html** of **HomePage** class :

```
 <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let countrylist of country">
          <h2 style="color: tomato">User Id: {{countrylist.name}}</h2>
          <h4>{{countrylist.nativeName}}</h4>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: there's no map method in native HTTP plugin from ionic, and when I use the http from angular I get CORS errors that I just can't get rid of.